# Save tmp files to Database

Tags: java, mysql, image, hibernate, struts

I've just learnt how to use the Struts 2 file uploader to upload a file. After it has been uploaded it saves the file as a .tmp file.

I would like to take this .tmp file and store it in the database then retrieve it on server-side and then display it as an image (that's what it is) on the client-side.

To do this I use a byte[] array right?

How do I do this?

**EDIT 1:**
I'm looking for the java server-side code required to convert the tmp file to an image as well as the struts/client-side code to display the image - i.e. `name="object.image"`

Comment: Personally, I tend to recommend against this--keep files on the filesystem and stream the data back.

Comment: That's what everyone says but if you test it yourself you'll find that MySQL has actually become a lot faster than what people think (In comparison to a regular file system)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use these types [The BLOB and TEXT Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)

EDIT

BUT  Dave Newton is right!!!

simple code, just change `fileinputstream` to your `inputstream`

```
 FileInputStream fis = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
      conn.setAutoCommit(false);
      File file = new File("myPhoto.png");
      fis = new FileInputStream(file);
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_PICTURE);
      ps.setString(1, "001");
      ps.setString(2, "name");
      ps.setBinaryStream(3, fis, (int) file.length());
      ps.executeUpdate();
      conn.commit();
    } finally {
      ps.close();
      fis.close();
    }
```

EDIT 1

If you are looking code that convert tmp to jpeg or other picture format, just read tmp and save to jpeg or other picture format (I think you are receiving picture format from client side but jsut with tmp extension if not, I do not think that this task is real!

Comment: Perhaps he is - it wasn't the question. I posted earlier about file systems vs database storage. There is a reason why I'm using a database instead of a file system...

Comment: OK, Never mind, you can use code like above to store binary files in mysql DB.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to get the image from the database and then show it on the jsp using struts by any chance?

Comment: How to get, just create query and select value from DB, after selection readblob, try to read doc, how to display in struts in action servlet just write response.setContentType("image/gif");             
            OutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream()            stream.write(ImgData); gif you should change to your type. lIke this

Comment: Is there a particular struts tag to use when displaying the image? let's say for example name="person.picture" in the struts tag.

Comment: Try to find in internet, yes there are tags, but I do not remember.